# Measuring against a future time in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'd like to be able to run a method which will measure Time.now against a future date, something like this:

```
def graduated?
  Time.now == # future date ? (puts "Congrats!") : (puts "Not there yet!")
end
```

I've tried entering the syntax from ruby docs for the future date as such: `2015-8-7`

but that is not correct. Could someone correct my syntax on how to hard code a future date to compare against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just enter `"2015-8-7"` that's a string, you'll want a `Time` object.  This should point you in the right direction:

```
2.2.0 :001 > other = Time.new(2015, 8, 7)
 => 2015-08-07 00:00:00 -0500 
2.2.0 :002 > Time.now < other
 => true 
2.2.0 :003 > Time.now > other
 => false
```

You can also use the `Date` object, and `Date.today`, `Date.new(2015, 8, 7)` and get similar results.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. Seems obvious now.

Comment: When does one need to require that? I didn't in irb. Worked fine. You do need to require 'date' to use Date, I know that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I didn't know that. It appears that `require 'time'` is only needed to extend the class `Time` to include [certain methods](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html) for parsing and convertng times.